# Exclude EnumerableEquivalencyStep on top level Assertion

Tags: c#, .net, fluent-assertions

I have this object from an external library that implements `IEnumerable<T>`. I just want to check the properties of this object and not the equivalence of the collection. I'm not interested in the stuff inside the `IEnumerable`. How can I exclude this from the assertion?

```
public class Example : IEnumerable<string>
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IEnumerator<string> GetEnumerator() => new List<string> { Id }.GetEnumerator();
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => GetEnumerator();
}
```

This is the test, which will fail on the `IEnumerable`.

```
(new Example {Id = "123", Name= "Test" } as object)
    .Should().BeEquivalentTo(new Example{Name = "Test"},
        o => o.Excluding(p => p.Id));
```

Doing this before the test this will work, but then I lose the ability to check any `IEnumerable` property on the class:

```
AssertionOptions.EquivalencyPlan.Remove<GenericEnumerableEquivalencyStep>();
AssertionOptions.EquivalencyPlan.Remove<EnumerableEquivalencyStep>();
```

Comment: Why not just test the individual properties? e.g. `source.Name.Should().BeSameAs(expected.Name);`

Comment: It's quite a large object to be testing in reality. Also, I want to be warned if properties are not under test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to workaround this [limitation](https://github.com/fluentassertions/fluentassertions/issues/860) is to add a dedicated equivalency step to handle `Example`.

```cs
using FluentAssertions;
using FluentAssertions.Equivalency;
using FluentAssertions.Equivalency.Steps;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    [ModuleInitializer]
    public static void SetDefaults()
    {
        AssertionOptions.EquivalencyPlan.Insert<ExampleEquivalencyStep>();
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        object subject = new Example { Id = "123", Name = "Test" };
        var expected = new Example { Name = "Test" };
        subject.Should().BeEquivalentTo(expected, o => o.Excluding(p => p.Id));
    }
}

class ExampleEquivalencyStep : EquivalencyStep<Example>
{
    protected override EquivalencyResult OnHandle(Comparands comparands, IEquivalencyValidationContext context, IEquivalencyValidator nestedValidator) =>
        new StructuralEqualityEquivalencyStep().Handle(comparands, context, nestedValidator);
}

public class Example : IEnumerable<string>
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IEnumerator<string> GetEnumerator() => new List<string> { Id }.GetEnumerator();
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => GetEnumerator();
}
```

Comment: Brilliant, that seems to do the trick.